# Using server-side to query an API instead of client-side?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios

currently I am calling an API with an API key that I do NOT want public, within a react component like so:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchData = () => {
    const url = `API_URL+${searchedValue}+process.env.API_KEY`;
    fetch(url, { headers: { Accept: 'application/json' } })
      .then(res => res.json()
      .then((json) => {
        setData(json.data || []);
       }))
    .catch(err => console.error(err)); // eslint-disable-line
  };
  debounce(fetchData());
}, [searchedValue]);
```

It works perfectly, but I know this is the wrong, because it is happening react-side and is easy for someone to discover my API key. I check the network logs and can see my query being sent to the API, API Key and all. After doing some reading on how to fix this, I have started to implement a basic server:

```
const express = require("express")
  app = express(),
  cors = require("cors");

app.use(cors());
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send({ message: "Server Connected" });
});
```

Now, I think I understand what needs to be done. Instead of calling the API directly in the react-side, I query my server with a request such as /api-$(searchedValue) (searchedValue because my query is dependent on the value a user searched). After this, my server queries the actual API, and returns the response it gets from the API.

Please correct me if my understanding of this flow is incorrect^

However, I don't have the slightest idea how to change these two files to make it happen. I have not found any tutorials online. Perhaps, can someone show me how I can achieve my intended goal? I am using ReactJS, Redux, Axios, Express, and Node.JS - Thanks in advance.

Comment: you could use [express-proxy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-http-proxy) else would need add in an http client like http/axios/node-fetch then pipe the result to res, a little more involved but not so much.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the concept that you are looking for is a **BFF** (back end for the front end), you can use this to hide your API keys.
Using that approach you have to create another endpoint in your express server to do the requests with your API keys and keep doing the request in the front but a simple one for your new endpoint on express server, so the keys would be only in your BFF (express).

Another approach would be **server-side rendering**, that you could execute and generate an HTML with your required data on the server and just send the complete page to the front. You can easily achieve that using Next.js.

Answer (score 0):

Well, using API keys in client side is risky and not secure. You will need a server somehow in the lifecycle of a Webapp. You can send only the API keys to your front-end using express/hapi/Koa or other server-side frameworks. Just call that endpoint which provides you the API keys & initialize your client side store's (Redux/Recoil/Context) API credentials.

**Client**

```
//App.js
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchData = () => {
    fetch("/some-secure-endpoint", { headers: { Accept: 'application/json' } })
      .then(res => res.json()
      .then((json) => {
        setData(json.data || []);
        //redux approach
        dispatch(setCredentials(json));
       }))
    .catch(err => console.error(err)); // eslint-disable-line
  };
}, [searchedValue]);
```

But call the **API KEY** providing endpoint at the Top Level of your App so you can access it from any other component easily...

```js
app.get("/some-secure-endpoint", (req, res)=>{
  //...authentication & route security stuff 
  return res.json({...API Keys});
})
```

This is a classic approach and works for smaller-medium projects. Try something more secure by researching for some while.

Comment: Using this approach, I am only serving my frontend the API Key from the backend? If the main API query is being executed from the frontend, wouldnt the network still log the query rendering this approach redundant?

Comment: Yes, but I didn't say to send the Keys just open & that would be pretty dumb. You can hash or do other stuff with the API KEYS & then send to the frontend..

Comment: Or you can use `.env` files and prepend `REACT_APP_` in your key properties, e.g: `REACT_APP_API_KEY=whatever`. This can be accessed from the root files of your app with `process.env.PROPERTY_NAME`. But this can be also seen from the dev tools. The only way to secure it is to use your backend as a relay for the fetch request to another API, this involves micro services pattern & often used...Check this post of freecodecamp : [POST](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/private-api-keys/)